Mafia type movie where young boy needs to make a "hit" for his initiation
Set in America, likely to be New York with the mafia being of N.Y./Italian style.
A boy around 14 years old is in a room with a 'mafia boss' who might also be the boys uncle.  The mafia boss is tied up and gagged and the boy has been told by other mafia members that as part of his initiation he must shoot the guy that is tied up and gagged - if he does this he passes the initiation to be part of that mafia. The mafia boss that is tied up is 'in on the act' and just wants to see for himself that the kid is tough.  He knows that the gun is loaded only with blanks so in essence won't be able to shoot him.
The other mafia members leave the room to give the kid some time alone with the mafia boss he's been instructed to shoot. They wait outside the room in a corridor, talking and smoking knowing that if they hear a bang of the blank firing gun, then they know hes passed - however whilst they're waiting patiently outside, inside the room the gun jams and the kid just wants to pass the initiation so he goes ahead and thinks to pass the initiation test he has to think outside the box and kills the mafia boss by hitting him in the head with the gun.  During this murder, the mafia boss is clearly trying to stop the kid and to explain that its a set up and just an initiation, but it's too late and the kid kills him. 
The kid is pleased with himself that he has gone through with it and passed the test but then the mafia guys that were waiting outside think they've given the kid enough time and return to the room, only to find the boss dead and covered in blood.
The film I think was around in the 80's.

Thanks for improving the question. It sounds very familiar, but maybe because it's a well-known joke, only with a wife instead instead of a mafia boss ("so I had to beat her to death with the chair.") @steelersquirrel Doesn't the boy refuse to shoot the guy there?

@Walt Oh, gheez.  I thought that there was a gun jam or something and then a refusal.  It's been a while since I have seen it.  I should have said "might be" Knockaround Guys and not "pretty sure" :P

It was seen way before the making of 'Knockaround Guys', so it can't be that movie. Thanks for the input and suggestion though - much appreciated.

It reminds me of that joke where the FBI/CIA/KGB tried to hire an assassin: they find 3 men and for the final test they give them a gun, let them into a room and have them kill their wife. The first man straight out refused. The second man went in but came out tearful after 5 minutes, and said he cannot do it. The third man went in, came out, and said, "some idiot loaded the gun with blanks, I had to strangle her to death."
